# Recursive Towers of Hanoi Python Solution using Stacks

Tags: python, algorithm, stack

I was trying to solve the Towers of Hanoi problem using stacks. Here is my code:

```
Init_stack = [0,1,2,3]
Buffer_stack = []
Final_stack = []
n = len(Init_stack)
def move_disks(Init_stack, Buffer_stack, Final_stack, n):
    if n == 0:
        return
    elif n == 1:
        Final_stack.append(Init_stack.pop())
    elif n == 2:
        Buffer_stack.append(Init_stack.pop())
        Final_stack.append(Init_stack.pop())
        Final_stack.append(Buffer_stack.pop())
    else:
        move_disks(Init_stack, Final_stack, Buffer_stack, n-1)
        Final_stack.append(Init_stack.pop())
        move_disks(Buffer_stack, Init_stack, Final_stack,n-1)
```

This works perfectly fine when the size of Init_stack is small, say < 10. But when I ran this code on a size 100 Init_stack, the program took a very long time to complete. Can you tell me why it takes so long?

Comment: Using 100 disks means you have to do `2^100 - 1 = 1.27e30` moves. That may perhaps be too much for Python?

Comment: The tower of hanoi problem has exponential time complexit O(2^n) Specifically it takes 2^n - 1 moves. This is possibly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12383044/complexity-for-towers-of-hanoi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Towers of Hanoi requires `(2^n)-1` moves where n is the number of rings. Even extremely efficient solutions take a long time to go through that many operations in Python.

`(2^10)-1` is equal to 1023(as every computer scientist knows), but  `(2^100)-1` is a 31 digit decimal number.

Answer (score 0):

## You can also solve using recursion

It takes time because the problem complexity is of exponential type which requires huge time to solve.

[Click here for recursive code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wcxco.jpg)

Comment: This sample isn't that long, please include it to your answer.