# What makes speed of these recursive pieces so different?

Tags: c, performance, recursion, difference

I have to work out a recursive function to apply on an assignment(for which im not allowed to use the standard math library about the tower of Hanoi. I stumbled upon the following code which i thought would be a good piece for the assignment to work with, however it is impossible to run it for (n > 30) as it's just so slow:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int TOH(int,char,char,char);

int main()
{
    int n;
    printf("\nEnter number of disks:");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int c = TOH(n,'A','C','B');
    printf("\nTotal number of moves = %d \n ", c);
    return 0;
}

int TOH(int n,char x,char y,char z)
{
    int count = 0;

    if(n>0){
    count = TOH(n-1, x, z, y);
    count++;
    count += TOH(n-1, z, y, x);
    }
    return count;
}
```

While looking for a solution for the speed, i stumbled upon this code, which runs instantly while using recursion. I'm lost on where this difference in speed comes from:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

float count_moves(int);
float power(int);

int main()
{
    int STACKS;
    printf("\nEnter numbers of disks: ");
    scanf("%d", &STACKS);
    float total = count_moves(STACKS);
    printf("\nTotal number of moves: %.0f\n", total);
    return 0;
}

float power(int multi)
{
    if(!multi)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    else
    {
        return 2 * power(multi - 1);
    } 
}

float count_moves(int layers)
{
    if(!layers)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    else
    {
        return power(layers - 1) + count_moves(layers - 1);
    }
}
```

How is the second one able to instantly print something in the console, while the second one takes longer the bigger a number i make n/STACKS?

Comment: A quick glance: your original solution is the naive/standard implementation, which runs in exponential time based on size of stack.

Comment: I didn't know the mathlib has a ready-made `towers_of_hanoi` function ...

Comment: @Olaf It has really? :O

Answer (score 1):

Firstly I would suggest you to draw the recursion tree. See how big it becomes for pegs = 30. Refer to [Complexity for towers of Hanoi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12383044/complexity-for-towers-of-hanoi)
It has a complexity of O(2^n).
http://www.iitk.ac.in/esc101/08Jan/lecnotes/lecture32.pdf

The second solution is not computing it in the traditional way. It is making a single call. T(n-1) + c = O(n^2)

So, 2^30 vs 30^2. Guess, which one is faster!

See for yourself.

add a counter to the functions like
(make 'c' and 'd' global)

```
float power(int multi)
{
    printf("d = %d\n",d);
    d++;
    if(!multi)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    else
    {
        return 2 * power(multi - 1);
    } 
}

float count_moves(int layers)
{
    printf("c = %d\n",c);
    c++;
    if(!layers)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    else
    {
        return power(layers - 1) + count_moves(layers - 1);
    }
}
```

and see the number of times they are called.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the pointless parameters, the first algorithm is `count = (n > 0) ? TOH(n-1)+TOH(n-1)+1 : 0`. Each call to `TOH` results in two further calls to `TOH`. Its complexity is O(2^n). Each time that `n` goes up by one, costs will double.

The second is `(layers > 0) ? [something linear] + count_moves(layers - 1) : 0`. It's two tail-recursive methods but each call to either generates at most one further call. But it's "do this n times, and for each time, do this other thing n times" so that's n*n. It's O(n^2).

O(2^n) goes up a lot more quickly than O(n^2).

Answer (score 0):

Your first version follows the scheme that would actually compute the sequence of steps to move the rings. But you don't explicitly compute these steps; indeed, your `TOH` version ignores its arguments! (Except for passing them to recursive calls which also ignore them except for passing them to recursive calls.)

This means that `TOH`'s return value only depends on its first argument `n`. This also means that your two recursive calls with `n-1` will return the same value, so it suffices to all `TOH` once and use the return value twice. Changing the body of the `if` inside `TOH` to this:

```
int tmp = TOH(n-1, x, y, z);
count = tmp + 1 + tmp;
```

makes your code terminate immediately with the same answer as before. Note that you will probably get arithmetic overflow above an initial `n` value of 31.

By the way, GCC at level `-O3` seems to be smart enough to perform this optimization automagically on your original code, with no changes whatsoever.